# How to check for pipes in directory traversal?

Tags: python, file-io, pipe

I have a Python program that traverses a directory and generates md5sums. On one file it gets stuck. Running `ls -lA` I found that it has the attributes `prw-------`. Some googling later I found that this indicates a pipe.

How to check for pipes in my traversal? I just want to skip this file.

---

My code for traversing is:

```
for dirpath, _, files in walk(folder):
    for fname in files:
        print join(dirpath, fname)
        if not islink(join(dirpath, fname)):
            # do something with the file, here I pass it to myClass.
            myClass.addFile(dirpath, fname)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to test for pipes explicitly, you only want to look for files.

Use `os.path.isfile()`; it'll return `False` for a pipe, but `True` for an actual file:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mj mj 0 Sep  7 12:27 actualfile
prw-rw-r-- 1 mj mj 0 Sep  7 12:25 pipe

>>> os.path.isfile('pipe')
False
>>> os.path.isfile('actualfile')
True
```